# Adding and deleting comments using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, comments

I have created a simple add and delete comments system using php. Couple issues with it.

1. After I post a comment and I refresh the page, it'll post the same comment again.
2. I can delete the comment but it won't show that it's deleted until i refresh the page. And again once i refresh the page, it'll load back the duplicate comment.

So I am assuming my best option is go go with ajax route to do this without refreshing the page.
Say below is the basic setup to add and show comment.  How would you create the ajax for it?

**Add comment form**

```
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class="field-comment">
              <label for="name">Enter your comment</label><br>
               <input type="text" name="comment" size="60">
         </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Post">
      </form>
```

**Show comments**

```
<div id="show-comments"></div>
```

**Delete comment button**

```
<div class="delete_comment">
<a href="delete_comment.php?id=<?php echo $comment_id; ?>"><p><img src="images/icon_del.gif" alt="delete"></p></a>
</div>
```

---

So these are the delete functions I have in the head section of the website.

```
<script>
    function deleteClick () {
        deleteComment($(this).data('id'));
    }

    function deleteComment(id) {
        $.ajax('delete_comment.php', {
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function() {
                //Ajax successful: remove the comment div from your comment area
                $('.comment-' + id).remove();
            },
            error: function() {
                //Ajax not successful: show an error
                alert('An error occured while deleting the comment!');
            }
        });
    }
    $('.delete_comment').click(deleteClick);
</script>
```

**This is the delete div on say index.php**

```
<div id="comment-<?php echo $comment_id; ?>" class="comment">
                    This is a comment.
                    <a data-id="<?php echo $comment_id; ?>" href="#" class="delete_comment">
                        <p><img src="images/icon_del.gif" alt="delete"></p>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

This is the delete function from delete_comment.php

```
$delete     =   $dbh->prepare("DELETE from comments WHERE comment-id = {$comment_id}");
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code?

Comment: You don't need a `form` to use AJAX. Hitting `enter` will submit to your `form`s `action` attribute. If you do, for whatever reason, want to use a `form`, don`t use a `submit` button. You need to use JavaScript to submit to your PHP page, which will return a value `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: I do not have javascript code to go with it. The comments system I have is done in php and mysql db. So I need bit of help with ajax as I am not familiar with it as much.

Comment: It's not AJAX without JavaScript. I will show you a simple AJAX request in my answer, which still won't solve your problem.

Comment: I understand. Please show me your example. It'll help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to display a live feed of your comments:

```
setInterval(function showcomments() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
csxmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
csxmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
csxmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function comments()
{
if (csxmlhttp.readyState==4 && csxmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById('show-comments').innerHTML=csxmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
csxmlhttp.open('GET','show_comments.php',true);
csxmlhttp.send();
}, 1000);
```

And this to send the id of the comment to the php script that will delete the comment from the database and then `alert()` you when it has been deleted:

```
function deletecomment() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
dcxmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
dcxmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
dcxmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function dcomment()
{
if (dcxmlhttp.readyState==4 && dcxmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    alert('Comment Deleted!')
    }
}
dcxmlhttp.open('GET','delete_comment.php?id=' + comment_id,true);
dcxmlhttp.send();
}
```

Is this what you were looking for??

Comment: Yes I suppose that's what I was looking for.  But looking at, I think it's better if go back and actually learn javascript step by step and come back to this. It looks like you put a lot of time into it. Thank you for this wonderful code.

Comment: It's not a problem! Let me know if you have any questions moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `thispage.php` more like:

```
<?php
  /* execute comments query -- echo $comments with the proper HTML formatting
     surrounding each comment */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
     <style type='text/css'>
       @import 'common.css'; @import 'thispage.css';
     </style>
   </head>
<body class='njs'>
  <div class='field-comment'>
    <label for='comment'>Enter your comment</label>
    <input type='text' name='comment' id='comment' maxsize='60' />
    <input type='button' name='pst' id='pst' value='Post' />
  </div>
  <div id='added-comments'>
    <div id='comments'><?php echo $comments;?></div>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='post.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='thispage.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now let's see `common.js`:

```
//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body, IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
bod.className = 'js';
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version)bod.className = className;
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
//]]>
```

Now your learning. Here's `post.js`:

```
//<![CDATA[
function post(where, send, success){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  var v = encodeURI(send);
  x.open('POST', where); x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  x.setRequestHeader('Content-length', v.length); x.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
  x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
      success(x.responseText);
    }
  }
  x.send(v);
}
//]]>
```

Now we need to see `thispage.js`:

```
//<![CDATA[
E('pst').onclick = function(){
  var cmt = E('comment').value;
  if(cmt !== ''){
    post('response.php', 'comment='+cmt, function(o){
      var div = doc.createElement('div'), del = doc.createElement('input');
      del.type = 'input'; del.value = 'Delete';
      div.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(o)); div.appendChild(del);
      E('comments').appendChild(div);
    });
  }
  else{
    // a comment was not entered
  }
}
var psts = E('comments').childNodes, cn, ip;
for(var i=0,l=psts.length; i<l; i++){
  (function(i){
    cn = psts[i].childnodes;
    for(var n=0,c=cn.length; n<c; n++){
      (function(n){
        ip = cn[n];
        if(ip.nodeName.match(/^input$/i)){
          ip.onclick = function(){
            post('response.php', 'delete='+ip.previousSibling.nodeValue, function(o){
              if(o){
                bod.removeChild(ip.parentNode);
              }
              else{
                // put error code here
              }
            });
          }
        }
      })(n);
    }
  })(i);
}
//]]>
```

How about `response.php`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
  $cmnt = $_POST['comment'];
  /* run database table column row INSERT based on $cmnt -- echo $cmnt when query
     is executed correctly
  */
}
elseif(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  /* run database table column row DELETE based on the actual comment which you
     can find in $_POST['delete'] -- Once you have executed query echo 1, which
     will go back to JavaScript page `onreadystatechange`
  */   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to alter your form a little bit:

```
<form action="#">
    <div class="field-comment">
        <label for="commentText">Enter your comment</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="commentText" id="commentText" size="60">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

Then, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), the script would be something like:

```
//Event handler for click on a delete button
function deleteClick () {
    deleteComment($(this).data('id'));
}

function addComment(commment) {
    //Create a new div with id "comment-[id]" containing the comment
    var $commentDiv = $('<div />', {
        id: 'comment-' + comment.id,
        'class': 'comment',
        html: comment.text
    };

    //Create the delete button with the attribute data-id, 
    //which will be used for deleting
    var $deleteLink = $('<a href="#" data-id="' + comment.id + '"/>', {
        'class': 'delete_comment',
        html: '<p><img src="images/icon_del.gif" alt="delete"></p>',
        click: deleteClick //Reference to the event handler we created above
    });

    //Add the delete button to the comment div
    $commentDiv.append($deleteLink);
    //Add the comment div to your comment area
    $('#show-comments').append($commentDiv);
}

function deleteComment(id) {
    $.ajax('delete_comment.php', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function() {
            //Ajax successful: remove the comment div from your comment area
            $('#comment-' + id).remove();
        },
        error: function() {
            //Ajax not successful: show an error
            alert('An error occured while deleting the comment!');
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    $('#comment-form').submit(function(event) {
        //Skip the form from submitting
        event.preventDefault();

        var commentText = $(this).find('#commentText').val();

        //Ensure commentText to not be empty
        if($.trim(commentText).length) {
            $.ajax('add_comment.php', {
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    commentText: commentText
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    //Ajax successful: call the addComment function
                    addComment(response);
                },
                error: function() {
                    //Ajax not successful: show an error
                    alert('An error occured while saving the comment!');
                }
            };  
        }          
    });

    //Find all delete buttons and add the event handler we created above.
    //This expects the delete buttons to have a data-id attribute containing 
    //the id of the comment that should be deleted
    $('.delete_comment').click(deleteClick);
});
```

This does the following:

1. Wait until the page is loaded (`$(function() {})`) and add an event handler to the form for the submit event
2. Skip your form from submitting (`event.preventDefault()`)
3. Check if a comment was entered (`if($.trim(commentText).length)`) and call the ajax function
4. Expects your add_comment.php to return JSON containing two fields: `id` and `text`. `id` is the id of the newly added comment and `text` just contains the added text
5. Create a new div with the id "comment-[id]" containing the comment and the delete button (I skipped the div around the delete since I think it isn't neccesary)
6. Add an event handler to the delete button which calls the `deleteComment` function on click
7. Excute an ajax call to delete the comment and remove the div containing the comment afterwards
8. Add event handlers to already existent delete buttons

This should do the job, but I haven't tested it. See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details about the ajax functionality. jQuery may seem a bit of an overhead for just this functionality, but it makes stuff like sending ajax and creating new DOM elements a lot easier. Please tell me if I need to clarify something.

**Edit**

As requested in the comments this is an example for a div containing a comment and a delete button:

```
<div id="comment-1234" class="comment">
    This is a comment.
    <a data-id="1234" href="#" class="delete_comment">
        <p><img src="images/icon_del.gif" alt="delete"></p>
    </a>
</div>
```

A click on the delete button takes the value of the attribute `data-id` (`$(this).data('id')` in the code) and calls the function `deleteComment` with the id as the attribute (1234 in this case). The function sends an ajax request and deletes the div with the id "comment-[id]", so in this example "comment-1234".

Comment: Ok this code is easier to understand. My question is, do I put all those functions in a js file and reference it in the head of the site? As I see it, those functions will be corresponding through delete_comment.php and add_comment.php, which i have.

Comment: Correct, just create a new js file (e.g. comments.js) and don't forget to include jQuery before it. I will slightly alter the code later since functionality for already existent delete buttons is missing and I think I did some mistake with adding the event handler to newly created delete buttons, too.

Comment: Read your update and yes, understanding the code you want to use always is a good thing :)
I still altered the code, though, so it is complete now and you (or someone else) can use it. Good luck with your comment system.

Comment: Since last night, I have a better understanding of your code.  I am going to take it step by step. Right now, I am only going to try and delete a comment.  My only question is, who does the 'id' in your delete function correspond to?  Can you please create the html delete button/div that matches your js code?  That would help me a ton.

Comment: I added an example for a comment div.

Comment: Looks good. I thing I noticed is that you have the div#comment in the your delete function, while in the html you have it as a class="comment". Shouldn't both be either a class or a id?  Second, You have multiple delete functions in your js file.  I can see how one them corresponds to the delete div but I am not sure how these are used. function deleteClick () and $('.delete_comment').click(deleteClick);

Comment: I've added a new answer, please check it.

Comment: Ahh I see. the #comment-' + id is where my comment id will go. You put the numbers 1234 as an example. Got it.

Comment: I believe I have it all correct now. Though it's not working yet. Please check the delete functions <script> code that I posted above. Perhaps I might be missing something in there.

Comment: You shouldn't post your code as an answer to your own question (at least not if it doesn't answer the question). You can use [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/1/edit) to show an example of your code. Just skip the ajax request, since it isn't necessary for your current problem anyway.

Comment: About your questions: The div has both, a class and an id. The class isn't used for the code at all, I only added it for possible styles in yous CSS. About the multiple delete functions: the `deleteClick` is just the event handler for the delete buttons (I probably should have called it `onDeleteButtonClick` or something like that). It just calls `deleteComment` with the data-id of the button that caused the event.

Comment: I looked at your code and it looks good so far, except for 2 points: 1. You use `$('.comment-' + id).remove();` instead of `$('#comment-' + id).remove();`. Since there isn't any div with the class "comment-1234" this won't work. 2. You don't wait until the document is loaded before you call `$('.delete_comment').click(deleteClick);`. This causes the code to be executed before the delete buttons were actually created by your PHP code, so none of them will get the handler. You can use jQuery for that, as i did in my code above. See the [jQuery documentation](http://bit.ly/1gPweZn) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the JS bin. That really helps.  As for your other points, I did the update. It's a new example but same function. Please check it here. http://jsbin.com/gibaf/2/edit?html,js

Comment: So what I get now is the error message(listed within the js function) if I try to delete the avatar.

Comment: There were a few problems in your bin:
1. You don't need `<script>` tags in the JS part of the bin

Comment: 2. jQuery was missing. You can add it with the "Add library" at the top
3. You included the `deleteClick` and `deleteComment` functions in the `$(document).ready` call. It still works this way, but you only need to include the part of your code, that depents on a ready document and since functions aren't called directly the only code that needs a ready document is the event handler declaration for the buttons
4. An ajax call won't work in jsbin.
See my updated version [here](http://bit.ly/1jo45Io)

Comment: I was actually calling jquery before.  I think there may be a confusing as to how i have the page setup with functions. So here it is http://jsbin.com/biyac/1/edit?html   . After adding $(document) to part of the code(as your example), I get no error; but It doesn't delete either.

Comment: Looks good now and works for me. Does the ajax request get called? Do you get any output in the console (Ctrl+Shift+K in firefox or F12 in other browsers)?

Comment: I do not get any output in the console. I only get # in the url bar. For eg. edit_record.php#  I guess delete_avatar.php is not being called for some reason.